# Laravel 7 Not Rendering Updates on Production

Tags: php, laravel, production

I pulled my updates on production but they are not reflecting, the files/updates are there but it's just not rendering, all the views/routes updates .

I tried restarting the Server but nothing,
I cleared all cache (lists below) but still no luck .

php artisan cache:clear

php artisan route:cache

php artisan config:clear

php artisan view:clear

rm -rf bootstrap/cache/*/*

I also updated the composer and dumped the autoload but still nothing .

Comment: have you checked code is it latest code .? and not rendering ?

Comment: Its difficult to know what you mean exactly by "not rendering" as that could refer to various things, one thing, are you using a vue application at all? if so, did you run the npm run process?

Comment: yup the files/updates are there, the directory of the subdomain to the root_file is correct .

i even put a die() function, but nothing, it still loads the previous files .

Comment: i must be missing something here, i just could'nt figure it out .

Comment: I once had this and the reason was a syntax error in a blade file